# how can I linearize a constraint of the form sum(min(x(i),y(i))) for a linear optimisation problem?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, optimization

I have an linear optimisation problem with the objective :

$ max PortfolioSpread(x_1,x_2,....x_N) = ∑_{i=0}^N(x_i*s_i)/budget$

s.t.

1. $∑_{i=0}^N x_i = budget$  (+ other constraints)
2. $∑_{i=0}^N min⁡(x_i,y_i)≥C$

where decision variables $x_i$ represent market values, $y_i$ represent current holdings expressed in market values while C is the constraint value.

how can I linearize the second constraint?

Comment: What does sum(x(i) , y(i) ) mean? Also the min operator in the title is missing in the body text

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz just edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: maybe this is useful https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/how-to-linearize-min-function-as-a-constraint

Comment: please clarify the question: what is x and y? how do they differ? why do you multiply x by s? and what is s?

Comment: The objective function represents portfolio spread so x is market value, s is bond's spread and budget is total portfolio value while y represents current holdings. I've managed to get a solution on math.stackexchange:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4455537/how-can-i-linearize-a-constraint-of-the-form-sum-minxi-yi-for-a-line